# getting error in updating a field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I started with nhibernate where i need to create an application which pperforms add,update aand delete functionality
my Add and Update works fine
But while deleting the field ineed to change the flag to True .... but some how i am unable to do that
my controller

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Product_Master pm = new Product_MasterService().GetProduct_Data(id);
                   return View(pm);
    }

 [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Delete(Product_Master Prod)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                new Product_MasterService().DeleteProd(Prod);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(Prod);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

in my view

```
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
```

Hobby_Master

```
<div class="display-label">Product_Id</div>
<div class="display-field">
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.product_Id)
</div>

<div class="display-label">Product_Name</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.product_Name)
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
}
```

i have used nhibernate and mvc
and written the function in Product_MasterService()
as follows

```
 public bool DeleteProd(Product_Master Prod)
    {
        log.Debug("Start");
        ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenWriterSession();
        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

            try
        {
            Prod.Deleted = 'T';
            session.SaveOrUpdate(Prod);
            transaction.Commit();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                transaction.Rollback();

            log.Error(ex);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.Dispose();

            if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
                session.Close();

            log.Debug("End");
         }            }
```

Can any one please help me with that......

Answer (score 0):

you need to close your session calling session.Close();

Comment: you put it after the return, so it's never called. put it before the return.

Comment: could you put your actual code? with the try&catch and everything?

Comment: What is the value of session.FlushMode ?

Answer (score 0):

I think ivowiblo is right, you cannot return value from try/catch. You can use local variable:

```
        var hasSuccessSave = false;
        try
        {
            Prod.Deleted = 'T';
            session.SaveOrUpdate(Prod);
            transaction.Commit();

            hasSuccessSave = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                transaction.Rollback();

            log.Error(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.Dispose();

            if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
                session.Close();

            log.Debug("End");
         }    
         return hasSuccessSave;
```